# Заполнить listbox случайными числами

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть приложение с элементом управления listbox, как заполнить этот самый listbox случайными числами?

Может можно сначала создать массив с случайными числами, но как тогда числа перенести в listbox?

Со строкой понятно:

`SendMessage(hList1, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, LPARAM(TEXT("Любой текст")));`

Как таким же способом число добавить?

Всё это варим в WINAPI с помощью C++

Вобщем вот кусок кода, который создаем массив случайных чисел, конвертирует их в символы и пытается занести в листбокс, как итог в листбоксе идет 1 символ и потом полная абракадабра

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  mas[i] = rand() % 10; 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
  char str[11];
  sprintf_s(str, "%d", mas[i]); //конвертируем в символ 
  SendMessage(hList1, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, LPARAM((&str[i]))); 
}
```

Comment: Ну сконвертируйте число в строку, `sprintf` же есть.

Comment: Можно пример?
Также вопрос, потом, что бы с числами работать(сравнивать и т.д.) назад конвертировать?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm и http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm

Comment: `std::to_string`, `std::to_wstring` - вам случайно не это надо?

Comment: Ну хорошо, допустим число я сконвертировал в строку, будет у меня массив символов, как тогда отправить в листбокс всё это дело?

Comment: а что делает `LPARAM(ТЕХТ(...))`?

Comment: Добавляет строку, но проблема в том так вот `SendMessage(hList1, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, LPARAM(TEXT(str[i])));`
добавлять он не хочет

Comment: и так не работает

Comment: Вобщем вот кусок кода, который создаем массив случайных чисел, конвертирует их в символы и пытается занести в листбокс, как итог в листбоксе идет 1 символ и потом полная абракадабра

`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   mas[i] = rand() % 10;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
   char str[11];   
   sprintf_s(str, "%d", mas[i]); //конвертируем в символ
   SendMessage(hList1, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, LPARAM((&str[i])));
  }`